# Is there a way to rename a sound card in Mac OS X?

Tags: audio, macos

I have multiple sound cards connected and would benefit from being able to rename them from their device name to something like "Headphones", "Surround system", etc. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The Sound Card’s name comes from the Device itself, which “publishes” its name. The operating system reads the name from there. I don’t believe you can rename it, but you can definitely go to **/Applications/Utilities/Audio MIDI Setup** and create an Aggregate Audio Device (with the names you want) and select the input/outputs of each.

For example, you can create your headphones like this:
[image]

Comment: That's what I suspected. Thank you for the answer though, it seems to be the closest to a solution of this.

Comment: Funny thing on macOS 10.13.5: Volume control is not possible on macOS. I would have to use the hardware button of the USB Sound Blaster HD now (which is somewhere hidden inside my table...).

So this is unfortunately no good solution :-(

Comment: Some external USB cards have their own hardware volume control and are outside of OS X’s realm. I have a sapphire focusrite 8i8 and I need to adjust volume via the hardware knob.