# How can I rename audio devices in macOS 12.0.1?

Tags: audio, usb, macos

I've already seen [Is there a way to rename a sound card in Mac OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/272/53510) and [Is it possible to rename an USB or Bluetooth audio device?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/418876/53510) but they didn't help.

I want to be able to rename the USB sound devices shown here since I keep forgetting which is which.

And I need the names to persist even after lots of unplugging and replugging-in.

[image: screenshot]

I've achieved this on my [Ubuntu computer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1313183/how-do-i-rename-audio-devices-in-ubuntu#comment2370469_1354231); it's got to be possible on Mac, too.

Comment: Here is how to do it on Windows 10: https://superuser.com/a/1811923/74576